# Need to show 24 hrs to 12 hrs in timepicker jquery

Tags: jquery-ui

I have used the  `$('#start_time').timepicker({ timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss tt' });` .

But it still showing the 24 hours format.

I need to show the 12 hours format in timepicker with AM and PM.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What jQuery plugin are you using?

Comment: can you provide a link to this addon / plugin?

Comment: http://trentrichardson.com this one i userd

Comment: Is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/ar7en/

Comment: no i need in separate... like i need to display only the hours and minutes and the second... no need to display the date in that. i have showed in the separate text box.

Comment: Same, works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/ar7en/1/

Comment: Same url not working here friend

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks friends i found issue.

That code should be like

`$('#start_time').timepicker({
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss tt',
            showSecond:true,
            ampm: true
    });`

Answer (score 4):

Its depends on which jquery plugin you are using.
@mangala, suggest also right. I want to add litle more, as I use
[jquery.datetimepicker.js](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) 
 Sample code is:

```
$("#start_time").datetimepicker({
    datepicker:false,
    format:'g:i A',
    formatTime: 'g:i A',
    mask:'29:59 99',
    step:5,
    ampm: true
});
```

It will helps you.
  This will give output as
[image]