# how to set datetimepicker in 12 hours format in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, format, datetimepicker

My datetimepicker's dropdown is displaying the date in `yyyy/mm/dd` format and time in 12 hours format. The problem is when I select a date and a time, the time gets displayed in 24 hours format. Whereas I wanted the time to be displayed in 12 hours format.

Here is my code:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    dayOfWeekStart: 1,
    lang: 'en',
    formatTime: 'h:i a',            
    step: 05
});
```

Comment: are you using any further plugins than jQuery?

Comment: Have you tried `formatTime: 'h:i A',`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to show 24 hrs to 12 hrs in timepicker jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587506/need-to-show-24-hrs-to-12-hrs-in-timepicker-jquery)

Comment: no i am not using any other jquery plugins

Answer (score 1):

I have figured this out. Kaushal Shah was close, but the output into the textbox was not showing in 12 hour format with his solution. You need to add the formatTime part as well as the format part, seen below.

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    dayOfWeekStart: 1,
    format: 'g:i a'
    lang: 'en',
    formatTime: 'g:i a',            
    step: 05
});
```

The solution I needed also contained more date information in the format section, so it looked more like this:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'D M-d-Y g:i a',
    formatTime: 'g:i a',
    lang: 'en',
    step: 15
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up using a modified version of this. 
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'm/d/Y g:i A',
        lang: 'en',
        formatTime: 'g:i A',
        step: 1
    });

Answer (score 0):

http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

- hours12: true

Should be a usefull link.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: This only gives you the options of 0:00 to 11:00, and doesn't change your format to 12 hours.

Comment: any update? Im currently facing a similar issue,

Answer (score 0):

Correct Code is:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    dayOfWeekStart: 1,
    lang: 'en',
    formatTime: 'g:i a',            
    step: 05
});
```

Or you can also try this:
'datetimepicker.CustomFormat = "HH:mm:ss tt";'

Comment: This works for the picker itself, but the time in the input box still displays the time in 24 hour format.

Answer (score 0):

Works!

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    formatTime: "hh:mm A",            
    step: 60
});
```